# How can I see that the resultant of two polynomials can be expressed by their coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, resultant

I define the *resultant* of $f_1, f_2$ by $\prod (x_i-y_j)$ where $x_i, y_j$ are the roots of $f_1, f_2$. Then how can I see this can be expressed by the coefficients of $f_1,f_2$?

Comment: I alluded to this in my answer to your original question.  You can show that the coefficients are symmetric with respect to permutations of the $x_i$ and permutations of the $y_i$, and this implies that they can be expressed in terms of symmetric polynomials in the roots, i.e. the coefficients of the polynomials.

Comment: @Slade I didn't see it, sorry. That is what confuses me. I have not learned about symmetric polynomials and I tried to look up online but just failed. So could you please explain more? The first coefficient you mention the the coefficient of which polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\prod_{i,j} (x_i-y_j)$.  Work over a field $k$, and also assume that $f_1,f_2$ are monic.

$g$ is a polynomial combination of the $x_i$ with coefficients in $k(\{y_j\})$.  Clearly, it is symmetric, i.e. permuting the $x_i$ does not change $g$.

By the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), this implies that $g$ is a polynomial combination of elementary symmetric polynomials $e_i$ of the $x_i$, which are just $\pm$ the coefficients of $f_1$.

By the same argument, applied to $g$ with coefficients in $k(e_i)$, we can write $g$ as a polynomial combination of the coefficients of $f_1$ and the coefficients of $f_2$.